# bootstrap (add node) localhost in chef

Tags: chef

**Problem**. Following command line

```
knife bootstrap 127.0.0.1 -r 'recipe[chef-client]' -x user -p password --sudo
```

returns

```
Bootstrapping Chef on 127.0.0.1
WARNING: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 -- Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

**Expected** that this command will succeed and after it

```
knife node list
```

will return

```
[
"127.0.0.1"
]
```

SSH server is working fine on localhost and `ssh user@127.0.0.1 -p password` works as expected.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the problem with the invocation is that you specified the password with the `-p` option, which `knife bootstrap` uses to specify an alternate ssh port. You wanted to use the `-P` (capital P), which the right option for specifying the password to the bootstrap command.

And, as Justin has indicated, bootstrap is likely not technically necessary if you already have chef installed to the point where you can run 'knife' commands. You should be able to fire off a 'chef-client' to enroll your node to the server (perhaps needing the validation key with `-K` option, if it's not already installed/available in /etc/chef). Once registered to your server, you can issue `knife node run_list add` commands to add the appropriate roles/recipes to the runlist, then invoke another `chef-client` to get it to take effect. Then again, `bootstrap` does it all in one command, so it's not a terrible option.

Comment: Agree with William. I posted the complete steps to enroll a node with Chef Workstation installed on the Chef server. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72916269/772481

Answer (score 1):

And you must add the IP and NODENAME(Hostname) to /etc/hosts:

```
127.0.0.1 NODENAME
```

And then split % knife bootstrap 127.0.0.1 -r 'recipe[chef-client]' -x user -p password --sudo
to two steps:

Step 1:

```
% knife bootstrap IP_ADDRESS -x ubuntu -P PASSWORD --sudo
```

Step 2:

```
% knife ssh name:NODENAME -x ubuntu -P PASSWORD "sudo chef-client"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting a connection refused, then an SSH connection could not be opened because either:

- SSH is not running on the system.
- A firewall rule is blocking access to port 22.
- SSH is running on a port other than 22.

That said, "knife bootstrap" is intended to be used to set up remote systems with Ruby/RubyGems, install Chef and configure it to connect to a configured chef server (from your local knife configuration). For more information about the "knife bootstrap" command, see:

- knife help bootstrap (in chef 0.10+)
- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Knife+Bootstrap

Also, the node name will be the detected fully qualified domain name (typically output of `hostname -f`), unless specified with -N NODE_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

> knife bootstrap 127.0.0.1 -U USER -N NODE_NAME --sudo --use-sudo-password -y --connection-password PASSWORD

This command works for me on localhost. I saw it at https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/9404#issuecomment-597424916.

But as William and Justin said, you can use `chef-client` to enroll your node to the server.